# SQL Server : CRUD Editor that will track data changes

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm looking for a tool that allows CRUD changes to SQL Server data. Our company currently utilizes a product from Pro Data called DBU (database utility) to make IBM DB2 / AS400 changes. This tool tracks CRUD activity, including before and after data changes. Then it produces a log that can be reviewed for audit purposes.

I tried several tools that track object level changes on the server, including SQL Server built-in tracking, however this is not the desired affect. We would like to expose a utility to a group of users and track only that particular activity.

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I won't use a own product for this.

You have two simple ways to do it on your own.

1. You can use CDC (Change-Data-Capture) which will do this automatically. You can retrieve the changes afterwards for some time. (If you don't need that every value is hold back for ever)
2. You can create an Before-Update trigger, which will generate a own log for a record before and after the insert. You can just query those log table and everything is fine. The end-user won't see anything of this, he can use Access, SSMS or whatever to achieve the changes.

Comment: CDC Will not work  if we alter the table after enabling CDC

Comment: Yes this is the case. CDC will work further but ignore the new columns. But it's not a big deal. Just re-enable the CDC with the new columns and make a backup of the old captures.
Trigger may be needed to changed too, but it's much more cheaper, easier to maintain and upgrade and you have everything in your own hands. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CDC(Change Data Capture)
It will track changes.

But if you alter the table, CDC Will not work..

you can handle this by ...

```
  1. Copy all data from change table to another table...



  2. Disable CDC For that table..



  3. Alter table...



  4  Enable CDC For that Table..
```

CDC Works fine. it is assynchronous with transactions.

```
--Enable CDC For DB
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db 

--Disable CDC For DB
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_db

--Enable CDC For Table
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
@source_schema = N'dbo',
@source_name   = N'MyTable',
@role_name     = N'MyRole',
@filegroup_name = N'MyDB_CT',
@supports_net_changes = 1

--Disable CDC For Table
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_table
@source_schema = N'dbo',
@source_name   = N'MyTable',
@capture_instance = N'dbo_MyTable'
```

Comment: But CDC will just work for a specific time. That's the point. If he needed the history for ever, this won't work really good. You can raise the retention time in CDC but this will slow down CDC after many months of usage. He still needs to back those logs up and clean CDC afterwards.